# How to make comma disappear if there would be only zeros after it?

Tags: excel, number-formatting

I'd like to have numbers displayed the following way:

```
1250000 -> 1,25M
2000000 -> 2M
300000  -> 300k
```

So, if the number is smaller then 1 million, then display (number/1000)k;
if it is over a million then display (number/1000000)M.

So far I have

```
[>=1000000]0,00  "M";[<1000000]0 "k"
```

The problem with that is it displays, for example, 1000000 as 1,00M.

I could change to

```
[>=1000000]0,##  "M";[<1000000]0 "k"
```

but that displays 1000000 as 1,M.

Does anyone know how to make the comma disappear for multiples of 1 million?

Comment: Please state what programming language and library you are using.

Comment: I thought the excel tag would be enough.

Comment: Huh. I didn't see that. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a few commas in your format code (I'm working with US localization). For the number format on your cells, use `[>=1000000]#.##,, "M";[<1000000]0,"k"`. This will give you:

```
1250000 -> 1.25M
2000000 -> 2.M
300000  -> 300k
```

To get rid of the . in 2.M, you can use a conditional format. When the number is a even multiple of 1,000,000, use a different format.

1. Select you cells, and Conditional Formatting -> New Rule...
2. Select "Use a formula..." and enter `=MOD(CellAddress,1000000)=0`
3. Click Format, and set the custom number format to `[>=1000000]#,, "M";[<1000000]#,"k"`

In step 2, you can also use `=MOD(H30,1000000)<4900` if you are dealing with non-round numbers. This should give you:

```
1250000 -> 1.25M
2000001 -> 2M
 300000 -> 300k
1000000 -> 1M
1005000 -> 1.01M (Rounded up)
```

Comment: Thanks, conditional formatting indeed solves the problem. I was just interested whether it can be done using custom number formatting.

Comment: Yes, @FaragóDávid, it's nice to keep it simple when you can, but I don't think it's possible in this case. Thanks for accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small UDF (User Defined Function) to address this:

```
Function formatLargeNumber(myValue As Long) As String

If myValue < 1000000 Then
    formatLargeNumber = CStr(Round(myValue / 1000, 0)) & " K"
    Exit Function
End If

If XLMod(myValue, 1000000) < 5000 Then
    formatLargeNumber = CStr(Round(myValue / 1000000, 0)) & " M"
Else
    formatLargeNumber = Format(CStr(Round(myValue / 1000000, 2)), "#.00") & " M"
End If

End Function
Function XLMod(a, b)
    ' This replicates the Excel MOD function
    XLMod = a - b * Int(a / b)
End Function
```

You can apply this straight into the spreadsheet by typing:

```
=formatLargeNumber(cellreference)
```

Or test it using this sub:

```
Sub testFunction()
    Dim x As Long, y As String
    x = 1005001 'change his to test
    y = formatLargeNumber(x)
    Debug.Print y
End Sub
```

Have a look here when you want to know more about UDF:
[User Defined Function (Excel Easy)](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html) or [Creating UDFs (Better Solutions)](http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/user-defined-functions-creating.htm)